# Cython: SIMD and OpenMP doesn't work well together

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, cython, simd, intrinsics

Assuming my 2D data's size is a multiple of 8 in each direction.

This is a toy example to illustrate the problem for a much more complex problem I'm actually dealing with. I am aware this can be done much more easily with cython or numpy for this simple example.

```
cdef extern from "immintrin.h" nogil:  # in this example, we use AVX    
    ctypedef float  __m256
    __m256 _mm256_loadu_ps  (float *__P) nogil  
    __m256 _mm256_mul_ps    (__m256 __A, __m256 __B) nogil
    void   _mm256_storeu_ps (float *__P, __m256 __A) nogil   


cdef float multiply_sum_SIMD ( float [::1] A, float [::1] B, int m , int simd ) nogil:
    cdef:
        int k, j, l
        float s = 0.0
        float *out_AB  = <float *> malloc( simd * sizeof(float) )        
        __m256  m_A, m_B, m_AB

    for j in range(m):
        k    =  simd * j  
        m_A  = _mm256_loadu_ps( &A[k] )
        m_B  = _mm256_loadu_ps( &B[k] )

        m_AB = _mm256_mul_ps (  m_A , m_B )        
        _mm256_storeu_ps( &out_AB[0], m_AB )
        for l in range(8):
            s = s + out_AB[l]            
    return s
```

So here is my cython cpdef to use the above function running single thread and result agrees with numpy version.

```
cpdef float Sum_Cython_ST ( float [:,::1] A, float [:,::1] B ):    
    cdef:        
        int   max_row = A.shape[0] , max_col = A.shape[1]
        float s = 0.0
        int   i, j

        # integer variable related to SIMD
        int simd = 8
        int remainder, m = <int>( (max_col - 1) / simd) + 1, chk = max_col % simd

    for i in range(max_row):        
        s = s + multiply_sum_SIMD ( A[i,:], B[i,:] , m, simd)        
    return s
```

Now if i switch the outer loop to use prange with nogil

```
for i in prange( max_row, nogil = True):
    s = s + multiply_sum_SIMD( A[i,:], B[i,:], m , simd )
```

then I start getting weird problems:
1. It complains that 's' is being reference before defined  (but that was defined above) 
2. If I switched s += multiply..... , then the error disappeared and compile without error but result is completely wrong, nan in my case.
3. If I switched the multiply_sum_SIMD to a function that doesn't uses SIMD and just have simple loop inside. Results agree with numpy version again (single or multi-thread).

I don't understand that why running this single thread is fine but as soon as I use prange, these problem pops up. Please help.

Comment: Also, you leak `<float *> malloc( ... )` by returning without freeing it.  Like we told you in a previous question, just store into a local array like `float tmp[simd]`, not a dynamically-allocated array.  Don't use `malloc`; you don't need or want it because you don't want that storage to stay allocated after this function returns.  Make `simd` a `constexpr int` if you need compat with MSVC (which doesn't allow C99 variable length arrays), or just use `8` because you're already using `_mm256` intrinsics.

Comment: There's also _a lot_ to be said for "just write it in C and wrap that C code in Cython". `prange` doesn't give you the control you want over OpenMP; SIMD intrinsics don't work with Cython hugely well. You could stop fighting with Cython and just write the code you want directly

Comment: @PeterCordes: prange doesn't divide up the column part I think. Not sure. I thought each of the "i" pieces is ran separately but within each piece, no further division, so the column should still be a multiple of 8.  I'll use the local array, forgot about that advice. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidW I feel like I'm very close to getting it all. Ultimately, I will switch to C++ but a final push. One last piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Oh, I didn't really understand the code the first time I looked at it.  Yeah if it's just parallelizing over `i` that shouldn't be the problem.  `multiply_sum_SIMB` (typo?) is called similarly in both cases, but with only the first 2 args given.  Maybe still worth adding an assert() to check that the range is a multiple of the vector width.